# Only showing questions marked by my own tags

Tags: support

This seemed like a question that's been asked over and over again to the oblivion of pains but when I've googled it, I didn't get that much relevant info.

However, according the the last reply in [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20322/how-can-i-see-only-my-interesting-tags-in-stack-overflows-list-of-questions), once one's picked one's tags, the rest are supposed to disappear automagically.

That doesn't happen in my FF.
What can I be doing wrong?!

Comment: I don't see any answer in that question that says the rest should disappear automagically.

Comment: @BoltClock "*You can use http://stackexchange.com/ - at the top there's "tagged questions" then you edit your "My Tags" to include your favourite tags, you then can view the recent activity, newest, and 'no answers' tabs as usual - and it only includes the tags you want to*"

Answer (score 4):

If all you're trying to achieve is filtering results to tags you're interested in, here's a workaround.

First if you select any tag, you'll see the search box is updated to your selected tag:

[image]

You can now add `or` syntax to add additional tags and you will see the `questions tagged` respond to what you have typed:

[image]

Not sure about any limitations on the amount of tags you can enter, I tried 8:

[image]

Finally, you will notice that the URL is specific to any search you have done:

[image]

So construct a search that you're interested in and bookmark it.

Comment: Of course, there are several other ways to [filter questions by multiple tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17003/filtering-questions-by-multiple-tags).