# How to hide all questions except the ones containing the Favorite tags?

Tags: support, tags

At the moment it seems that if a user would like to ignore all tags except ten that all more than 40k different tags need to specified individually under the `preferences menu` as `ignored tag`.

Comment: You could just visit the list for that tag and it will only show you questions that have the tag on it...

Comment: Question has been updated

Comment: You realize that this would mean that you would only ever see questions that only use those ten tags, meaning someone adding any tag not in that set of ten hides the question from you.  Are you really sure you want that?  I can't see why anyone would.  If you just want to see questions that have at least one of your 10 tags, you just need to favorite those ten tags.

Comment: What's wrong with PHP? [Everyone loves PHP!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/231057/213671)

Comment: So it is possible to gray out all tags except the Favorite ones?

Comment: What's the point? I don't like javascript, but I would still be interested in reading about some good javascript questions.

Comment: @utrecht Virtually all questions using your few favorite tags are also going to include some other tags as well.  By ignoring them you're likely to remove virtually all questions from your feed.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations. I have removed all ignored tags. When I check new questions, the ones containing the favorite tags are marked.

Comment: See my answer here for a workaround: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265247/57475

Answer (score 0):

You currently can't do this from your preferences at the moment. However it would be possible to write your own script that does it.

In one of the recent podcasts, the SE team talked about something related to this.

Here is a *sort of related answer* of mine [Too many questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216096/too-many-questions/216106#216106)

Answer (score 0):

In contrary to gunr2171, I don't have so much time to read questions about PHP and other technologies not interesting for me :-)

Check this [List of Questions with in favorite tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255651/list-of-questions-with-in-favorite-tags), it contains a few tips to use tags with wildcards in search box to limit displayed questions. You can use it for old questions.

For new questions I use 'Filtered questions' from StackExchange - it will show you newest questions, based on your defined filters for example Favorite tags (very useful).

As many others, I'd love to have Favorite tab, which would only show questions with your favorite tags, but it looks like there is strong opposition for that... I really don't know why, as the ones that wouldn't like to use it, would just continue to use SO as they do.